# How to select multiple vertical characters in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have the following setup (but really 30 LI items) in Notepad++

```
<ol>
<li>1. test1</li>
<li>2. test2</li>
<li>3. test3</li>
<li>4. test4</li>
<li>5. test5</li>
<li>6. test6</li>
<li>7. test7</li>
</ol>
```

But I want to replace the first 3 characters after each `<li>` item so that it looks like this...

```
<ol>
<li>test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
<li>test3</li>
<li>test4</li>
<li>test5</li>
<li>test6</li>
<li>test7</li>
</ol>
```

Is this possible with with any UI tools in Notepad++? Or do I have to manually go by hand and fix my HTML page...

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there why don't you use Column edition :) 
it's pretty easy with it :)

it's something like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click then you drag all the column you want :)

here is a link : http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html

Answer (score 1):

Clad Clad suggest a [nice way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22967980/1870232), but you can also use `regex` search and replace if lines are too many that are scrolling off the screen.

- Find what:   `(<li>)\d+\.\s*(.+</li>)`
- Replace with: `\1\2`
- select Regular Expression check box, click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[image]

Comment: +1 for more in-depth pages. I will keep this mind for the bigger projects

Answer (score 0):

Just replace **`\d+.`** (with a space in the end) by nothing. Remember to check on the **regular expression** option.